# Use php variable in a Json file

Tags: php, json

I simply want to create a language file in json and receive variables to display on my page, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

What I want to achieve (code):

```
$json = file_get_contents('lang/en.json');
$useLang = json_decode($json);

echo msg($useLang->user->hello, 'rawohah211');
// Hello rawohah211
```

My json right now:

```
{
  "user": {
    "hello": "Hello {user}"
  }
}
```

Is this possible to achieve with PHP and json?

Comment: What is `msg()`? You could use `str_replace` for `{user}` and the parameter 2 value..

Comment: msg() is simply a php function that creates a p-element so that I can add styling to any message. I'll check into str_replace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the key skills in programming is breaking problems down into smaller pieces. In this case, you have a few things to work out:

1. How do I load JSON into something I can work with in PHP, and how do I then access the parts of it?
2. How do I convert an altered version of that back into JSON?
3. How do I replace a particular section of a string?

Number 1 you've already sorted - `json_decode`. By default, it gives you a mix of objects and arrays, so in your example the string can be read and written as `$useLang->user->hello`. (I personally prefer the all-array structure returned if you use `json_decode($json, true)` in which case it would be `$useLang['user']['hello']` instead.)

Number 2 is just as easier - `json_encode` does the exact opposite of `json_decode`.

Number 3, you'll note, doesn't mention JSON or arrays or objects - you have a string `"Hello {user}"` and you want to make it read `"Hello rawohah211"` or something similar. For that, you just need [`str_replace`](https://php.net/str_replace). If you need to match a *pattern* (lots of similar strings), look into [`preg_replace`](https://php.net/preg_replace).